# PHP convert time format

Tags: php

In my database I have a date like `2013/11/12` and it must be converted in `12th November 2013`. Here there is my code:

```
$a=mysqli_connect("localhost","usern","pass","my_mk7vrlist");

//as you can see I'm getting the value of the date from a MySQL database

$res= mysqli_query($a,"SELECT * FROM 0_vrs_europe ORDER BY `vrs` DESC, `date` ASC LIMIT 0 , 150");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }

mysqli_close($res);
?>
```

The `$row['date']` contains the date in `2013/11/12` format and it must be converted in `12th November 2013` as I have already said. How could I do it?

I have googled the function `date` but I can't understand how to use it here.

Comment: http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php PHPs date function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date()`s second parameter:

```
$formatted = date('jS F Y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Comment: This would output `3th`

Comment: you need to use `S` for the suffix

Comment: @cmorrissey: Yes, as I posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = date("jS F Y", strtotime($row['date']));
```